# PIXI container bigger than stage?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

While trying to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi#introduction) for pixi.js I came across something I can't quite understand.

I set the size of the `renderer` to 512 by 512, but when trying to render the `stage` with a `TilingSprite`, the scene gets cut before it reaches the end of the canvas, like so:

[image]

**EDIT:** the blackness you see on the image above is still within the 512 by 512 canvas itself, it is not the browser's background.

Instead of reproducing the floor tile forever, the scene just becomes black after 100 pixels or so.

What's happening here?

Here is the code:

```
PIXI.SCALE_MODES.DEFAULT = PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST;

//Aliases
var Container = PIXI.Container,
    autoDetectRenderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer,
    loader = PIXI.loader,
    resources = PIXI.loader.resources,
    TextureCache = PIXI.utils.TextureCache,
    Texture = PIXI.Texture,
    Sprite = PIXI.Sprite;
    TilingSprite = PIXI.TilingSprite;

var stage = new Container();
    stage.scale.set(3,3);
var renderer = autoDetectRenderer(512, 512);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

PIXI.loader
    .add("src/tileset.json")
    .load(setup);

function setup() {
    var id = PIXI.loader.resources["src/tileset.json"].textures;

    let dude = new Sprite( id["dude"] );
    let blob = new Sprite( id["blob"] );
    let floor = new TilingSprite( id["floor"] );
    let chest = new Sprite( id["chest"] );

    //Position the chest next to the right edge of the canvas
    chest.x = stage.width - chest.width - 48;
    chest.y = stage.height / 2 - chest.height / 2;

    stage.addChild(floor);
    stage.addChild(chest);
    stage.addChild(dude);

    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you don't set scaling? Also does it work properly, if you manually set the TilingSprite size? Like new TilingSprite( id["floor"], renderer.width, renderer.height)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `TilingSprite` takes width and height as parameters as well, and while I erroneously assumed that it would just repeat until the `stage` was completely covered, it has a default value of `100px` for both width and height:

```
@param {PIXI.Texture} texture - the texture of the tiling sprite
@param {number} [width=100] - the width of the tiling sprite
@param {number} [height=100] - the height of the tiling sprite
```

Initializing it with the dimensions I wanted solved the issue.